# Invertible elements of a power series ring

Tags: field-theory, power-series

Let $F$ be a field and $F[[x]]$ be the power series ring with coefficients in $F$.  It seems if $\alpha, \beta \in F[[x]]$, with $\alpha^{-1} = \beta$, then all coefficients of the product $\alpha * \beta$ are identically zero with the exception of $\alpha_0, \beta_0$, which need to satisfy $\alpha_0 * \beta_0 = 1$.
Is this a true statement?

Comment: Yes, this is correct, since $1= 1+ 0x+ 0 x^2 + 0x^3 + \dots$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is a ring with $+$ and $\times$.